# RTLabel issue (bold links)

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, nsstring, uilabel

I use RTLabel from https://github.com/honcheng/RTLabel
I need to use links in text, I use:

```
moreInfoString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ <a href='%@'>%@</a>", text, httpReferense, title];
RTLabel *descriptionSourceLabel = [[RTLabel alloc] init];
descriptionSourceLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
descriptionSourceLabel.delegate = self;
[descriptionSourceLabel setText:moreInfoString];
```

but the text is in links is bold. How to cancel bold text in links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that my way is not the best, but anyway:

in `- (void)render` function I replaced:

```
else if ([component.tagLabel caseInsensitiveCompare:@"a"] == NSOrderedSame)
        {
            if (self.currentSelectedButtonComponentIndex==index)
            {
                if (self.selectedLinkAttributes)
                {
                    [self applyFontAttributes:self.selectedLinkAttributes toText:attrString atPosition:component.position withLength:[component.text length]];
                }
                else
                {
                        [self applyBoldStyleToText:attrString atPosition:component.position withLength:[component.text length]];
                    [self applyColor:@"#FF0000" toText:attrString atPosition:component.position withLength:[component.text length]];
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (self.linkAttributes)
                {
                    [self applyFontAttributes:self.linkAttributes toText:attrString atPosition:component.position withLength:[component.text length]];
                }
                else
                {
                        [self applyBoldStyleToText:attrString atPosition:component.position withLength:[component.text length]];
                    [self applySingleUnderlineText:attrString atPosition:component.position withLength:[component.text length]];
                }
            }

            NSString *value = [component.attributes objectForKey:@"href"];
            value = [value stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"'" withString:@""];
            [component.attributes setObject:value forKey:@"href"];

            [links addObject:component];
        }
```

with (added linkShouldBe_regularFont property - my custom property, if linkShouldBe_regularFont == YES, the font will be regular):

```
else if ([component.tagLabel caseInsensitiveCompare:@"a"] == NSOrderedSame)
        {
            if (self.currentSelectedButtonComponentIndex==index)
            {
                if (self.selectedLinkAttributes)
                {
                    [self applyFontAttributes:self.selectedLinkAttributes toText:attrString atPosition:component.position withLength:[component.text length]];
                }
                else
                {
                    if (!self.linkShouldBe_regularFont) {
                        [self applyBoldStyleToText:attrString atPosition:component.position withLength:[component.text length]];
                    }
                    [self applyColor:@"#FF0000" toText:attrString atPosition:component.position withLength:[component.text length]];
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (self.linkAttributes)
                {
                    [self applyFontAttributes:self.linkAttributes toText:attrString atPosition:component.position withLength:[component.text length]];
                }
                else
                {
                    if (!self.linkShouldBe_regularFont) {
                        [self applyBoldStyleToText:attrString atPosition:component.position withLength:[component.text length]];
                    }
                    [self applySingleUnderlineText:attrString atPosition:component.position withLength:[component.text length]];
                }
            }

            NSString *value = [component.attributes objectForKey:@"href"];
            value = [value stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"'" withString:@""];
            [component.attributes setObject:value forKey:@"href"];

            [links addObject:component];
        }
```

Comment: The link attributes solution below should be the correct one

Answer (score 2):

The `linkAttributes` property can be used for custom styling of the links. If you set `linkAttributes` to be an empty dictionary, the links will not be styled.

```
// Remove all link styles
descriptionSourceLabel.linkAttributes = @{};

// To change only i.e. link color
descriptionSourceLabel.linkAttributes = @{@"color": @"red"};
```